# How to make a VBox Windows XP guest from installation CD?

Tags: windows-xp, installation, virtualbox, virtual-machine, iso-image

I have a sudden need to have a Windows XP guest machine (VirtualBox) and have both a Reinstallation CD (including SP3) as well as a valid Windows XP key that I purchased years ago and never used.

So I created the VM in VirtualBox and configured its VDI. Normally, with Linux guests, at this point I just go into the VM's `Settings >> Storage` and point the IDE drive to an ISO that I have stored locally on my host's file system.

In this case, it's a physical CD. I searched the CD high and low and do not see an ISO file anywhere on it (I'm not a Windows guy). Instead, the best I've been able to find is a file called `setup.exe`, which I assume is the executable that bootstraps the entire installation process. Even if I'm correct, I'm still not sure how to point my Windows XP VM to the `setup.exe` file on the CD.

So I ask: given this scenario, how do I configure the VM properly so that `setup.exe` (or whatever else is necessary to install Windows XP on the guest VM) is ran the first time I start it up? Thanks in advance!

**Edit**: Please note, I'm not interested in pirated ISOs or illegal copies! I believe I already have everything I should need to install the OS, I'm just having trouble "connecting the dots".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Connect the virtual CD drive of the VM to the physical CD drive of your host. The option should be just below the "Choose a virtual CD/DVD disk file..." option. Or use `dd` to make an ISO image from your CD and connect that to the virtual drive.

```
dd if=/dev/sr0 of=winxp.iso bs=2048
```